# Если класс 2 наследуется от класса1, а класс1 от класса0, могу ли я использовать функцию класса0?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, множественное-наследование

Откровенно простой вопрос, но я слаб в ООП.

```
class Class0 {
    protected:
        void func() {
            ...
        }
}

class Class1 : public Class0 {
}

class Class2 : public Class1 {
}
```

Могу ли я в Class2 использовать функцию func() из Class0?

Comment: А попробовать слабО? :) https://ideone.com/LDsKYE

Comment: Да. Это одна из возможностей ООП. Иначе наследование теряет сильно в смысле. Отвечаю, зная Python и не зная C++, но это вряд ли важно.

Comment: спасибо, понял.

Comment: @Сергей Golang со своим ооп вам может сломать моск

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, да, спасибо, интересно. Правда, я написал "наследование теряет сильно в смысле", а не "ООП теряет сильно в смысле". Wikipedia же говорит про Golang " Наследование реализации отсутствует", так что всё нормально. Там концептуально нет наследования / типового полиморфизма. То есть, я вижу, что если наследование есть в ООП языка, то есть и наследование методов, если же его нет, то и вопроса нет.

Comment: @Сергей Я к тому что ООП, это не про полиморфизм и наследование, а про представление сущности как объекта :) с переходом на голанг это для меня лично заиграло новыми красками, т.к. язык ОО, а ни полиморфизма нормального ни наследования нет ни абстракций, зато есть интерфейсы, утиная типизация, и встраивание :)